# How to select objects without UV maps

Tags: uv

I am using Blender 2.80. I exported selected meshes to Substance Painter and got a warning that some objects has no UV maps.
Is there any quick way to see what objects have missing UV maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a build in way, but you can run this script to select meshes with no UN layers:

```
import bpy

for obj in (o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.type == 'MESH'):
    obj.select_set( len(obj.data.uv_layers) == 0 )
```